# Tamanho de campo decimal SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tipagem

Estou fazendo um formulário, e na documentação do banco existem alguns campos numéricos que estão com o tamanho dividido em 2 parâmetros. Ex:

> Campo: Custo
>
> Tipo: NUMERIC
>
> Tam.: (12,4)

O que significa esse tamanho divido e qual tamanho eu teria que validar no *front*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode depender do banco de dados que está usando (originalmente não tinha essa informação na pergunta).

Este é um tipo numérico que permite casas decimais com exatidão, então pode ser usado para valor monetário ou outro tipo de valor que precisa ser representado exatamente.

Tem banco de dados permite uma precisão de 10 elevado a 38, então são números bem grandes.

Exemplos:

```
123.4567
12345678.9012
```

Em geral esses números são gravados como inteiros (neste caso um inteiro que tenha 12 dígitos). E indica quantas casas deve aplicar a vírgula, que é chamada escala, então o que realmente é gravado no primeiro caso é o número 1234567, e ele é mostrado ou usado para cálculo dividindo por 10000 (4 zeros). Mas isso é detalhe que não importa para você.

Você pode gravar números que não se enquadrem nessa característica em alguns bancos de dados, outros podem impedir você de gravar um número com mais dígitos ou mais casas decimais, alguns poderão fazer ajustes por conta própria, portanto você deve consultar a documentação para saber o que o mecanismo que está usando adota e decidir como operar.

O SQL Server impede gravar valores fora deste padrão então validar antes pode ser interessante, eu faria em quase todos os casos de uma forma ou de outra (pode ser que a entrada do dado já impeça um valor errado).

Por isso eu sempre falo que as pessoas se iludem que um dia podem trocar o banco de dados por outro se criar uma camada extra, tem muito detalhe que precisa ser diferente, você só consegue abstrair tudo se fizer o mínimo denominador comum, o que destrói a performance. Aí tem gente que falará mal do DB relacional, acha que microsserviço é melhor e adota outras bobagens só porque ela toma uma decisão errada antes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Algo que eu achei que jamais deveria acontecer no SQL-Server: se eu informei mais casas decimais do que é necessário para o armazenamento, eu esperava que ele apenas truncasse/arredondasse as casas extras. Quando por algum azar do destino foi gerado um número com 30 casas decimais, o SQL-Server reclamou e eu precisei "truncar na mão" para no máximo 25 casas. Gambiarras do dia-a-dia

Comment: Acabei de editar, to num sql server

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu prefiro o erro em caso assim, porque você pode não querer aquilo, ser explícito é melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Este tamanho dividido significa a porção inteira e fracionária. É uma forma indicada para gravar registros monetários. Então o valor seria armazenado no banco de dados assim:

CUSTO
57.9870

Sobre validar no front-end vai depender dos requisitos de negócio.